# Converting an MS Access web app to an SQL Server web app

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ms-access

I have an ASP.Net web application that runs off of Access databases. I want to convert the application to run off of SQL Server. Will this be a simple process to do? I am thinking that it only involves changing the queries that run on an Access format so they can run on an SQL Server.

Is it that simple or is there be more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Migrate DB to SQL Server with MS SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access
2. Review migrated DB and verify that tables have been migrated and that column data types have been set properly.
3. Modify connection string in web.config so that it is now pointing to the SQL Server DB
4. Review your query code and modify as necessary.  The T-SQL used in SQL Server will be different from the JET SQL used in Access.  Do a search for Quick-Access-JET-SQL-to-T-SQL-Cheatsheet and you'll find a list of differences.

[Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access](https://web.archive.org/web/20171002153826/http://www.microsoft.com:80/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42656)

[SQL Server Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)